# Como obter uma terceira variável de uma junção de duas variáveis no php

Tags: php, php-5

tudo bem?
eu estou com o seguinte problema em obter uma variável no php
segue o código:

```
<?php
$video1="welcome.mp4";
$video2="movie.mp4";
$video3="ends.mp4";

$num_id="1";
$get = '$' . "video" . $num_id; 
$file = $get;
echo "<a href=Player.php?file=$file'>Play</a>";
?>
```

mas quando vou ver o resultado no html
aparece a variável bruta $video1
mas eu quero o resultado como: welcome.mp4

HTML Resultado:

```
<a href="player.php?file=$video1">Play</a>
```

HTML - Expectativa:

```
<a href="player.php?file=welcome.mp4">Play</a>
```

Comment: desculpe, não tinha percebido.
eu editei as variáveis de video1, video2, video3 adicionando $
mas mesmo assim o caso é o mesmo

Comment: Tente o seguinte ```echo "<a href=Player.php?file=" . $file . ">Play</a>";```. Utilize essa contatenação, assim ele irá colocar o valor certo na variável, antes de ir pra view.

Comment: não funcionou. resultado é: 
. video .

Comment: O você quer fazer é `$file = ${$get}`, mas não vejo sentido em criar essa variável a mais.

Comment: exatamente isso que eu precisava
realmente não precisava dessa variável "$file" a mais
tava mais era em busca de fazer funcionar dessa forma com ${$video1}

vai ficar perfeito no meu código agora. obrigado a todos, de verdade.